# How to get Enum.reduce until list get empty Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to get all companies list from Intercom. with `per_page` it doesn't give more than 60 at once. There is another endpoint as 
`https://api.intercom.io/companies/scroll`, this gets `scroll_param` to get other companies and so on.

The scroll params come with the first request and then you can use it until the companies will become `[]`.

I have created this method as

```
  defp companies(scroll_param) do
    url = if scroll_param, do: "#{@intercom_url}/companies/scroll?scroll_param=#{scroll_param}", else: "#{@intercom_url}/companies/scroll"
    headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer #{@intercom_token}", "Accept": "Accept:application/json"]
    response = HTTPoison.get(url, headers) |> elem(1)
    case response.status_code do
      200 -> {:ok, response}
      _ -> {:error, response}
    end
  end
```

And I am trying do such as

```
companies = companies(nil)
scroll_param = companies["scroll_param"]
all_companies =
  Enum.reduce(companies["companies"], [], fn company, acc ->
    if companies["companies"] == [] || is_nil(companies["companies"]) do
      {:halt, acc}
    else
      acc ++ company["companies"]
    end
  end)
```

First, get all companies with nil `scroll_param` and then Do Enum.reduce until companies become `[]`.

when there is no company left to show, the request gives

```
%{"type":"company.list","companies":[],"scroll_param":"b85a7745-d423-49bf-91b2-72a513b781e4"}
```

My problem is I don't know how to use recursion here, So I can get all the companies in on variable as `all_companies`

The first first request give such values

```
%{ "companies": [{ "type":"company",
  "company_id":"smithbrothersltd.co.uk",
  "id":"5c7817185170c3ed1cf9d07a",
  "app_id":"f9c1fd60de50d31bcbc3f4d8d74c9c6dbc40e95a",
  "name":"Smith Brothers",
  "remote_created_at":1551374104,
  "created_at":1551374104,
  "updated_at":1551795637,
  "last_request_at":1551795636,
  "monthly_spend":0,
  "session_count":3,
  "user_count":6,
  "tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[]},
  "segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"53834904c1bbf82df800b256"}]},"plan":{},"custom_attributes":{"creation_source":"api"}}
  ],
  "scroll_param":"b85a7745-d423-49bf-91b2-72a513b781e4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be better done as a gen_server that could control the requests flow in case of errors (backoff, retries, etc), but that would mean knowing where it's being used and how. I don't think using `Enum.reduce` has any benefit over just declaring a module that does this. You would probably want to discern on the errors and status code other than 200 and explicitly decide if it's worth retrying, or logging the errors/status codes, etc. As it is it will machine gun 5 times in case of errors, fail on 5th consecutive error or non `200` response code. I'm assuming HTTPoison decodes the body as JSON when provided with the headers, otherwise you'll need to add a decoding step for the response too.

```
defmodule MyApp.Intercom do

  @intercom_scroll_url @intercom_url <> "/companies/scroll?scroll_param="
  @intercom_base_url   @intercom_url <> "/companies/scroll"
  @intercom_headers    ["Authorization": "Bearer #{@intercom_token}", "Accept": "Accept:application/json"]

  @max_retries 5

  alias HTTPoison.Response, as: Resp

  def get_companies(acc \\ [], scroll_param \\ nil, errors \\ [], retries \\ 0)
  def get_companies(acc, scroll_param, errors, retries) when retries < @max_retries do
    case get_companies_request(scroll_param) do
      {:ok, %Resp{status_code: 200, body: %{"companies" => []}}} ->
        {:ok, :lists.flatten(acc)}

      {:ok, %Resp{status_code: 200, body: %{"companies" => companies, "scroll_param" => n_scroll_param}}} ->
        get_companies([companies | acc], n_scroll_param, errors, 0)

      {:ok, %Resp{status_code: sc, body: body}} ->
        {:error, {:unexpected_status_code, {sc, body}}}

      {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
        get_companies(acc, scroll_param, [reason | errors], retries + 1)
    end
  end

  def get_companies(acc, _scroll_param, errors, _), do: {:error, {errors, acc}}

  defp get_companies_request(nil), do: HTTPoison.get(@intercom_base_url, @intercom_headers)
  defp get_companies_request(sp), do: HTTPoison.get(@intercom_scroll_url <> sp, @intercom_headers)
end

MyApp.Intercom.get_companies()
```

Comment: It just gave 100 companies. whereas 229 are available. what could be the problem you think?

Comment: also how are using scroll_params?

Comment: Also yes it dont decode JSON as well as your scroll_param is always empty

Comment: It should be decoding JSON otherwise it would match the 3rd clause. As for the `scroll_param` always being empty that's because the code as is is not extracting it on the 2nd clause, which you can do and substitute the `scroll_param` there

Answer (score 0):

If the `scroll_param` keeps the same across all the requests (except the first one, of course), then

```
all_companies = [scroll_param]  # The scroll param acquired by the first request
                |> Stream.cycle()
                |> Stream.map(&companies/1)
                |> Stream.take_while(fn 
                     {:ok, %{"companies" => []}} -> false
                     {:ok, _} -> true
                     {:error, _} -> false
                   end)
                |> Enum.map(fn{:ok, %{"companies" => companies}} -> companies end)
```

Then you prepend the companies fetched by the first request and `List.flatten` the result.